# How to take values in the column as the columns in the DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My current DataFrame is:

```
             Term  value
       Name
        A      1     35
        A      2     40
        A      3     50
        B      1     20
        B      2     45
        B      3     50
```

I want to get a dataframe as:
        
`Term   1   2   3
Name
  A    35  40  50
  B    20  45  50`

How can i get it?I've tried using pivot_table but i didn't get my expected output.Is there any way to get my expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.set_index('Term', append=True)['value'].unstack()
```

Or:

```
df = pd.pivot(df.index, df['Term'], df['value'])
```

---

```
print (df)
Term   1   2   3
Name            
A     35  40  50
B     20  45  50
```

EDIT: If duplicates in pairs `Name` with `Term` is necessary aggretion, e.g. `sum` or `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Name','Term'])['value'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Still didn't get my expected DataFrame

Comment: @UsmanMohammed - Why? There is some error? Or something else?

Comment: @UsmanMohammed - How working `df = pd.pivot(df['Name'], df['Term'], df['value'])` ?

Comment: I'm getting this ValueError

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape